# Как заставить Uploadify yiiext работать в хроме?

Tags: javascript, yii

Использую виджет Uploadify https://github.com/yiiext/uploadify-widget для yii.
Но в хроме он не работает. Просто не работает объект типа "application/x-shockwave-flash"ю
Как решить?

Answer (score 0):

Решения не нашел, поэтому использовал euploadmam расширение для yii. Используется HTML5 вместо flash